# Standalone DataTable in .Net

Tags: .net, datatable

Can I use the `DataTable` class like this:

```
DataTable client = new DataTable("client");

int primay_key = 1;

DataRow row = null;

row = client.findBy(primary_key);
```

After `findBy`, will the row object contains a row from the database?

I cannot find a example like that on the internet, looks like the .net
built in `DataTable` class is not what I thought it was.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to fill a DataTable before you can 'query' it:

Assuming you already have a SqlCommand object set up:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    DataTable dt;

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A DataTable is an object that models a database table in memory. On its own, a DataTable doesn't do any kind of database interaction. You first have to create a data adapter object that's appropriate for your database system, then use it to fill your in-memory DataTable.

Example:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Clients", conn); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
da.Fill(dt, "Clients");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a DataTable like that -- you might try DataTable.Rows.Find

Comment: erm, nope! The DataTable has not been folled with anything!

Answer (score 0):

A `DataSet` / `DataTable` is not a proper database as such. but can certainly be used for an in momory object model - but without most of the features you would normally associate with an RDBMS.

Comment: I was just about to say "Hey Marc, you're up late", but then realised you must be at the Summit...

Comment: ;-p Indeed. Just stopping in for a few moments, though ;-p

Answer (score 0):

I just do not want to use DataAdapter to fill dataTable, because for each different table in DB, I have to write same code again and again.

If dot net dataTable class is not associated with actual table in DB,
is there a product on market do that? A component, an open source project?

Comment: What you're looking for is called an ORM system. There are various free and open source ORM systems out there, NHibernate being the most popular. If you don't mind spending a little money, I've found OPF3 to be very good, as well.